How to access methods of a character class from outside the application after compiling it into an EXE?
I’m working on a closed-source C++ application: an OpenGL-based simulation game with aircraft (friendly and enemy). I want to integrate autonomous behaviors such as Hierarchical Task Networks (HTN) to handle complex planning like:

Assaulting an enemy.
Following an enemy aircraft.
Coordinating a platoon for team attacks.

I want the application to support plugins for these autonomous behaviors, enabling users to dynamically change or add new behavior without modifying the core application.
To achieve this I have tried the method below:
Aircraft Class
class Aircraft {
public:
    // Constructor
    Aircraft(const std::string& name, float speed, float altitude);

    // Member functions to simulate behaviors
    bool FollowTarget();
    bool AttackTarget();
    bool AvoidTarget();

    // Utility functions
    void setSpeed(float speed);
    float getSpeed() const;

    void setAltitude(float altitude);
    float getAltitude() const;

    const std::string& getName() const;

private:
    std::string name;    // Name of the aircraft
    float speed;         // Speed in units
    float altitude;      // Altitude in units
};

AircraftAPI Class
class AircraftAPI {
public:
    // Exposes Aircraft's FollowTarget method
    static bool FollowTarget(Aircraft* aircraft);

    // Exposes Aircraft's AttackTarget method
    static bool AttackTarget(Aircraft* aircraft);

    // Exposes Aircraft's AvoidTarget method
    static bool AvoidTarget(Aircraft* aircraft);

    // Utility methods for setting and getting properties
    static void SetSpeed(Aircraft* aircraft, float speed);
    static float GetSpeed(Aircraft* aircraft);

    static void SetAltitude(Aircraft* aircraft, float altitude);
    static float GetAltitude(Aircraft* aircraft);

    static const std::string& GetName(Aircraft* aircraft);
};

Plugin Interface
class IPlugin {
public:
    virtual ~IPlugin() = default;
    virtual bool initialize() = 0;
    virtual void update(float deltaTime) = 0;
    virtual void cleanup() = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
};


AttackPlugin Class
// AttackPlugin class
class AttackPlugin : public IPlugin {
public:
    AttackPlugin(Aircraft* aircraft) : aircraft(aircraft), attackCooldown(0.0f) {}

    bool initialize() override {
        return aircraft != nullptr;
    }

    void update(float deltaTime) override {
        attackCooldown -= deltaTime;
        if (attackCooldown <= 0.0f && aircraft) {
            AircraftAPI::AttackTarget(aircraft);
            attackCooldown = 3.0f;
        }
    }

    void cleanup() override {}

    std::string getName() const override {
        return "AttackPlugin";
    }

private:
    Aircraft* aircraft;
    float attackCooldown;
};

NOTE: This is not my actual code It's just for an example. My methodology is similar. How can I make my application independent of Attackplugin
I want to expose a C++ API to interact with the game, allowing users to instantiate classes, pass data, and invoke methods using native C++ objects and application characters can be controlled outside the application like inside plugin using HTN.
How can I implement this in such a way that the API must keep the application closed-source.

This looks like a general programming question that would be better off on Stack Overflow to me. It's also very similar to some existing questions there like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480357/how-to-implement-a-c-plugin-system-for-a-modular-application

Broadly speaking you could either access the plugin code via a DLL (or maybe an SO on Linux - haven't used them, so less sure about that) or add extensibility support with a scripting language. A third option is to handle things via network requests; that doesn't seem to fit your description - mentioning it for completeness.
